# Expandable row In Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

The below UI needs to be implemented with dynamic values. NGX-datatable allows you to create expandable rows, but I don't know how to do it.

[image: UI example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Expansion Panel from Angular Material.
Refer below link:
[ExpansionPanel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview)

Comment: i will try that,, thanks